# Getting Fatal error during transformation Java.net.connectException connection timed out:connect .While executing testng xslt report through ant

Tags: ant, selenium-webdriver, testng

```xml
<target name="testng-xslt-report">
    <delete dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt">
    </delete>
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt">
    </mkdir>
    <xslt in="${basedir}/testingtestng.xml" style="${basedir}/testng-results.xsl" out="${basedir}/testng-xslt/index.html" classpathref="testingtestng.classpath" processor="SaxonLiaison" >
        <param expression="${basedir}/testng-xslt/" name="testNgXslt.outputDir" />
        <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.sortTestCaseLinks" />
        <param expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS" name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter" />
        <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" />                             
    </xslt>
</target>
```

This is the build.xml. I have saxon-8.7.jar and SaxonLiaison.jar files having the specified path. I have JDK1.7/Jre1.7 in my machine, and I am using ant-1.9.1 version. Can any one suggest me how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.